# Update a column value with a loop iterator?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @selec nvarchar(max)

SET @i = 0

WHILE @i <= 25
    BEGIN
        SET @selec = 'UPDATE BOMT'+ LTRIM(STR(@i+1)) + '
        SET   [Scenario ID] = @i'
        SET @i = @i+1
        EXEC(@selec)    
    END
```

I'm trying to iterate through a list of 25 tables that I have (BOMT1, BOMT2, BOMT3, etc) and add the value of the iterator, `@i`, to every row in the column called scenario ID. I'm getting an error that says I need to:

> declare the scalar value @i.

Any help would be very much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I'm using a software for data cleansing that allows you to create macros in SQL. It would save me a lot of time to do it through a loop than creating 25 separate actions in the software. I'm not very well versed in SQL unfortunately

Comment: Yes, variable @i is not defined when EXEC is called. Did you mean this instead 'UPDATE BOMT'+ LTRIM(STR(@i+1)) + 'SET   [Scenario ID] = ' + LTRIM(STR(@i))?

Comment: `SET @selec = 'UPDATE BOMT'+ LTRIM(STR(@i+1)) + ' SET   [Scenario ID] = ' + STR(@i)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change things around a bit by getting your variable outside of the string, like you did in the select statement.

Try this

```
WHILE @i <= 25
    BEGIN
        SET @selec = 'UPDATE BOMT'+ LTRIM(STR(@i+1)) + '
        SET   [Scenario ID] = ' + LTRIM(STR(@i+1))
        SET @i = @i+1
        EXEC(@selec)   
    END
```